# Wait for a loop of calls in meteor

Tags: asynchronous, meteor, callback

I have a client only collection, I iterate through it and send each element to the server:

```
collection.forEach(function (entry) {
    Meteor.call(args, function (error, result) {
        if (error) {
             ...
        } else {
         ...
        }
    });
});
```

After all the elements have been processed I use them in other operations.
How can I wait until all the calls have finished? All the solutions I've found are for one call, but none of them address how to wait for a loop of calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way, basically after each call, check how many you have processed and if that's all of them, call your code you want to run next. This will run afterAllCallsMethod() even if there are errors, if you don't want it to run if there are errors just move it up to the else block and processed will not equal total ever if there are errors.

```
var total = collection.length;
var processed = 0;
collection.forEach(function (entry) {
    Meteor.call(args, function (error, result) {
        if (error) {
             ...
        } else {
         ...
        }
        processed++
        if (processed == total) {
           afterAllCallsMethod();
        }
    });
});
```